# How to install scikit-image when the installation appears broken

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, scikit-image

I'm a newbie in `Python`, coming from `R`, and I'm not a programmer, so please be patient if my question is quite silly or trivial, but I cannot find a solution by myself.

I'm using `Python 3.7` in Spyder, in a Windows 10 machine.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/tutorial_segmentation.html), and I've understood that I need the `scikit-image` module.

I've learned that external package should be imported in the same environment of Spyder, so I'm installing them from Spyder:

```
 ! pip install scikit-image
```

And I got this:

> Requirement already satisfied: scikit-image in
>   c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
>   (0.15.0) ...

Same for pillow, networkx, PyWavelets, imageio, decorator, numpy (those I suppose they're the dependencies modules). It seems I've what I need.

So I try the first command of the above mentioned tutorial, that is:

```
from skimage import data
```

But the results seems this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       from skimage import data
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\skimage__init__.py",
>   line 124, in 
>       _raise_build_error(e)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\skimage__init__.py",
>   line 104, in _raise_build_error
>       %s""" % (e, msg))
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'geometry' from 'skimage._shared'
>   (C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\skimage_shared__init__.py)
>   It seems that scikit-image has not been built correctly.

But I think that this is important:

> Your install of scikit-image appears to be broken. Try re-installing
>   the package following the instructions at:
>   https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/install.html

So I went to that link, but the standard installation is what I tried to do. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT1**:
I've followed the answer, I've run this:

```
!pip uninstall scikit-image --yes
Uninstalling scikit-image-0.15.0:
  Successfully uninstalled scikit-image-0.15.0
```

Then

```
!pip install scikit-image
```

And the result is that is `already satisfied`:

> Requirement already satisfied: scikit-image in
>   c:\users\me\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
>   (0.15.0)

And same for:matplotlib, networkx, pillow, imageio, PyWavelets, numpy, cycler, kiwisolver, pyparsing,python-dateutil, decorator, six, setuptools

---

**EDIT2:**, done in the anaconda prompt, already some package are already satisfied, so I restarted Spyder, and sending:

```
from skimage import data
```

Gives a different error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       from skimage import data
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\skimage__init__.py",
>   line 127, in 
>       from .util.dtype import (img_as_float32,
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\skimage\util__init__.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from .dtype import (img_as_float32, img_as_float64, img_as_float,
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import numpy as np
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\numpy__init__.py",
>   line 142, in 
>       from . import core
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ctypes__init__.py",
>   line 356, in **init**
>       self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>
> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 it's not a valid application of Win32

(the last line is translated by me) that I've searched, but despite is a rather well known problem, I cannot find a solution.

Comment: I see you are using anaconda, try to uninstall/install the package from within anaconda or with `conda install`

Comment: @Sparky05 , thanks,  in the anaconda prompt sending the same commands (without !) I succesfully uninstalled/installed the package, I restarted Spyder, and I got a different error, posted above.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the cause of your error or if it should look like this, I still see a mix of anaconda paths and system paths. You may try creating a new environment in anaconda and install all packages from anaconda inside this environment.

Comment: That was the right path: all the environment concept was not clear to me, with your comment, I've understood something new, thanks. If you add it as an answer, I'll gladly upvotes and mark as correct.

Comment: I've created an answer with some helpful links to the documentation of python environments and condo documentation for creation of them (if you don't have the gui, which is really easy to use). If you are new to `Python` and based on your `R` backround, I would suggest that you may take a look at jupyter notebooks, which has with its interactive cells a feeling closer to `R`.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Your problem showed me that allowing package installation with `!pip/!conda` in our console leads to very confusing and nasty issues, so I decided to deactivate it for our next version. Our console is meant to run Python code, not to run system commands. So users shouldn't use it to install packages through it because both pip and conda expect a real system terminal, not something that emulates a terminal but in reality is not.

Comment: Besides, you shouldn't use pip to install packages provided by Anaconda (like `scikit-image`) because most pip and conda scientific packages are incompatible (Pandas, Numpy, Matplotlib, etc), which means that using pip with Anaconda to install them usually corrupts Anaconda and you're required to reinstall it. So by forbidding pip/conda installation we can also show users a message saying that using pip with Anaconda is a really bad idea.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba thanks for your feedback. I'd like only to point out that I'm not an experienced Python/Spyder/Anaconda user, maybe a seasoned users doesn't have those issues, and remove a functionality could lead to other problems to them. Maybe showing a warning is enough (just my opinion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Proposed solution: creating a new (virtual) environment

From the given outputs, I would suggest creating a new environment to encapsulate all packages for your current development.

For help regarding environments together with anaconda you may want to look [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) or create them within the gui.

Some rational for using virtual environments in general you can find in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). 
In short: Environments are an easy way to have separated versions of packages for different projects and you separate your development from the system python installation, which may has different packages.

### Why virtual environment in your case?

Currently, it looks like a mix of packages from your system installation, paths like

> "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python..."

and installations of anaconda, with paths from

> "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib..."

probably this causes your problem (and probably will cause some more).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like something went wrong when you installed. You may need to reinstall it via:

```
pip uninstall scikit-image
pip install scikit-image
```

If there are any errors during the last step (save the output), then post it here. That will give a clue as to what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I've  `!pip uninstall scikit-image --yes` then `!pip install scikit-image`, and you can see the update in the question.

Comment: This works for conda uninstall scikit-image conda install scikit-image  too!

Answer (score 1):

1. pip uninstall scikit-image
2. conda install scikit-image

it seems that conda will install some other dependency packets.
And it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:-

```
pip uninstall scikit-image && pip install scikit-image
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55808104/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*